# Configuring a workflow summary on Github Actions

Tags: github-actions

I'd like to configure custom summary for my Github Action workflow, similar to how RollingVersions does theirs. After looking at the docs and scouring the internet, this doesn't appear to be the same as [Github Actions Job Summaries](https://github.blog/2022-05-09-supercharging-github-actions-with-job-summaries/).

Does anyone happen to know if this is configurable through GH workflows? If so, what's the name of this summary line so that I can look up docs?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called a "commit status", and there's a [REST API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/commits/statuses?apiVersion=2022-11-28#create-a-commit-status) for it. The summary string you talk about is set in the `description` parameter.

To set it from an Actions workflow, you could use the GitHub CLI like

```bash
gh api repos/OWNER/REPO/statuses/SHA \
    -f state='success' \
    -f context='Check context' \
    -f description='This check succeeded!'
```

resulting in a status that looks like

[image]

Consult the docs to see all the parameters available.